# C++: Is it okay to use decltype to copy types from my header files?

Tags: c++, c++11, decltype

I want to reduce the amount of maintenance I have to do to my code when things change.

In a certain header file I have something long and kind of verbose like this:

```
extern std::map<event_t, std::multimap<real_t, event>> event_schedule;
```

Then, in a cpp file, I thought it would be easier to actually declare it like so;

```
decltype(event_schedule) event_schedule;
```

Is there any reason **not** to?

Comment: i think that's why declytype is invented.

Comment: If you don't want to make a type alias (which might be useful in other parts of the code) then I don't see why you should not do that if you want to. It's certainly valid, and much less to write. Though it will make the code harder to understand as you have to search the code-base for `event_schedule` to find the actual type. An appropriately named type alias will probably be better in my opinion.

Comment: consider using a different name for your local variable. else, if you want to *refer* to the one in the header, make a reference or use `using`. else, if this is the definition of the variable, you're fine.

Comment: I think there's no reason to not use `decltype` but, what's the reason to no use `typedef`?

`typedef std::map<event_t, std::multimap<real_t, event>> eventSchedule;`

`extern eventSchedule;`

Comment: PaperBirdMaster, I'm pretty sure that's not even going to work unless you do `typedef whatever eventschedule_t` and `extern eventschedule_t eventSched`.

Comment: @kvanberendonck yeah, my bad, typo error. But `typedef`ing works as well as `decltype(instance) instance;`, imho looks neater. Or maybe better with `using eventSchedule = std::map<event_t, std::multimap<real_t, event>>;`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How is `decltype(event_schedule)` harder to understand than `event_schedule_t`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, there is no reason not to.

The only argument that can probably be made against that is that "you can't see the type". This argument has been brought up for `auto` quite a bit and has never really managed to "get attention". You usually care about what you can do with the type rather than how shiny the actual name of the type is really.